# Edit invisible rows for UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am working on an app in which I want to toggle the status of some devices on/off by changing the image view of the cell. I have my devices in a table view and I am setting the editing mode of the table view on a button click and it is editing fine, but the problem is that it only changes the image of the cells which are currently visible, whether or not I have previously selected some of the rows which are not visible right now. Here is my code.  Tell me what I am missing or what I should do to change the selected rows which are not visible.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
deviceTableVIew.rowHeight = 72.0;
[deviceTableVIew setAllowsSelectionDuringEditing:YES];
[deviceTableVIew setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing:YES];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mainBackground.jpg"]];
btnControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-conrol.png"]];  
[super viewDidLoad];
}

-(IBAction)control:(id)sender{
btnControl.enabled = false;
btnControl.hidden = true;        
btnCancel.enabled = true;
btnCancel.hidden = false;    
stateToggleToolbar.hidden = false;    
[self.deviceTableVIew setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)setDevicesOn:(id)sender{

NSArray *paths = [self.deviceTableVIew indexPathsForSelectedRows];
for (NSIndexPath *path in paths) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.deviceTableVIew cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"device-on-image.png"];
}

controlStatus = NO;        
btnControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-conrol.png"]];        
stateToggleToolbar.hidden = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume you have an array of custom objects or dictionaries somewhere that holds the information to populate your cells.)

A better strategy is to have your setDevicesOn: method update that data model to indicate what image you wish to display and, when it's finished, call reloadData.  Then, when cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called, you can set the cell's actual image based on that data element.

Comment: OK, so I need to type faster.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Table views don't maintain cells for every row.  As you scroll, the cells going out of view are recycled and used for the cells coming into view.

The "device on" state of each cell should not be stored solely in the cell's image.  You should have a model object for each row (or an array of states, etc) that maintains that state.  So in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can properly set up a cell that is coming into view.

Comment: Yes that's the thing I was missing. Thanks alot